# Как сделать аналог twitch'a?

Tags: php

Необходимо просто создание трансляций. возможно даже несколько одновременно.

> http://www.twitch.tv

Быть может, подскажете куда копать. пишу на PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На сколько я знаю Twitch использует RTMP протокол для вещания стримов. http://habrahabr.ru/post/174089/ статья как сделать свой RTMP сервер.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Было бы кармы больше плюсанул

Comment: @Koddi, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Пожалуйста, избегайте ответов, которые содержат лишь одну ссылку, старайтесь давать комментарии и пояснения.